# login to keycloak clients require multiple attempts after upgrade from version 12 to 18

Tags: gitlab, keycloak, quarkus, keycloak-services

We recently migrated to Quarkus distribution from v12 to v18 and we are getting issues in authentication problems for all clients we are using. We are able to log in Keycloak console successfully but after that separate screen apeears for gitlab login. When we try to search for the base URL multiple times we somehow get logged into the clients.
We get this error after login to Keycloak:
[gitlab error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzFyM.png)

I checked logs as well and got errors for CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR & USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR. I checked several options but nothing worked.

We are getting similar problems for Jfrogg artifactory and Graphana, errors are different but behavior is same.
Attaching screenshots for the same.

I checked multiple discussions but none matched the same.

Expected behaviour is: After successful login in keycloak I should directed to clients homepage directly.
[jfrog artifactory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGZ9Q.png)
[graphana error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzFyM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not an answer, but I suggest you get quarkus distribution working in v12, and then upgrade/migrate keycloak in steps - for example:

v12 wildfly -> v12 quarkus
v12 quarkus -> v15 quarkus
v15 quarkus -> v18 quarkus

There's a lot of changes going on from v12 to v18. After v12 quarkus works, you'll at least know that all the settings on your part still work in quarkus distribution and you can move on with the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for checking, but we have already upgraded our prod to 18, so we have to correct the behavior anyhow.
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.